# How to Query this in MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb

My items store in MongoDB like this :

```
{"ProductName":"XXXX",
   "Catalogs" : [
    {
        "50008064" : "Apple"
    },
    {
        "50010566" : "Box"
    },
    {
        "50016422" : "Water"
    }
]}
```

Now I want query all the items belong to Catalog:50008064,how to?
(the catalog id "50008064" , catalog name "Apple")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot query this in an efficient manner and performance will decrease as your data grows. As such I would consider it a schema bug and you should refactor/migrate to the following model which does allow for indexing :

```
{"ProductName":"XXXX",
   "Catalogs" : [
    {
        id : "50008064",
        value : "Apple"
    },
    {
        id : "50010566",
        value : "Box"
    },
    {
        id : "50016422",
        value : "Water"
    }
]}
```

And then index :

```
ensureIndex({'Catalogs.id':1})
```

Again, I strongly suggest you change your schema as this is a potential performance bottleneck you cannot fix any other way.

Comment: then how to query the catalogs ? like this ?db.products.find({ "Catalogs.50008064" : { $exists: true } } )

Comment: No, like db.products.find({'Catalogs.id':50008064}) which is a lot cleaner and faster.

Answer (score 0):

This should probably work according to [the entry here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24exists), although this won't be very fast, as stated in in the link.

```
db.products.find({ "Catalogs.50008064" : { $exists: true } } )
```